# Type 'FormikValues' is missing the following properties from type 'Exact<{

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik

I have the following form:

```
import { Field, Form, Formik, FormikProps, FormikValues } from 'formik'
import { NextPage } from 'next'
import React from 'react'
import { useCreateUserMutation } from '../generated/graphql'

const Register: NextPage = () => {
  const formikRef = useRef<FormikProps<FormikValues>>(null)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    nameInit = localStorage.getItem('name') ?? ''
    console.log(nameInit)
    if (formikRef.current) {
      formikRef.current.setFieldValue('name', nameInit)
    }
  }, [])
  const [register, { data, error, loading }] = useCreateUserMutation()
  return (
    <Formik
      innerRef={formikRef}
      initialValues={{
        name: nameInit,
      }}
      onSubmit={async (values) => {
            console.log(values)
            const response = await register({ variables: values })
            console.log(response)
          }}
    >
      {() => (
        <Form className="space-y-8 divide-y divide-gray-200">
          <div className="sm:col-span-2">
            <label
              htmlFor="name"
            >
              First name
            </label>
            <Field
              type="text"
              name="name"
              id="name"
              autoComplete="given-name"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="flex justify-end">
            <button
              type="submit"
            >
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  )
}
```

Everything was working fine until I introduced the lines:

```
const formikRef = useRef<FormikProps<FormikValues>>(null)
```

and

```
innerRef={formikRef}
```

Now `variables` in the line `const response = await register({ variables: values })` is red underlined with the message: `Type 'FormikValues' is missing the following properties from type 'Exact<{ name: string; }>': name ts(2739)`

When I run the code, the website works perfectly fine though and sends the data to the server as expcted with no errors.

How can I fix this warning?

---

Edit:
I checked the definition of the FormikValues type:

```
/**
 * Values of fields in the form
 */
export interface FormikValues {
    [field: string]: any;
}
```

When I add the line `innerRef={formikRef}` the type of `variables` changes from a dictionary to `FormikValues`

Comment: It seems like `register` demands on "name" property to be present on `variables` field and `FormikValues` doesn't have this prop. What is `FormikValues` type? Is it a type defined by you or imported from formik library?

Comment: @Temoncher Yes, it's a type I'm importing from formik. I've edited the post to better answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The problem

`FormikValues` type doesn't match signature of `register` function from `useCreateUserMutation`

## Solution 1

Replace `FormikValues` with `{ name: string }`. Should work as expected.

## Solution 2

Why do we even need this `useRef`? As I understand the only reason to keep formik ref is to be able to use `setFieldValue`. Maybe you should take a look at [useFormik](https://formik.org/docs/api/useFormik) which exports formik API directly or [useFormikContext](https://formik.org/docs/api/useFormikContext)

Comment: Solution 1: In my actual usecase I have some additional parameters. Do you think I could make another interface and cast it? Solution 2: The reason I took this approach is it was the top rated answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60358836/how-to-formik-setfieldvalue-in-useeffect-hook - Do you recommend to switch to one of the other solutions and if so why?

Comment: 1. What do you mean by "cast it"? 2. Yes, I think it is better to go for provided hooks instead of `innerRef`. Refs are mostly used to get direct access to something only in case nothing else works. Also the Formik documentation doesn't describe this approach, so I would stay away from it.

Comment: Makes sense - I will add a component which returns null and uses `useFormikContext` to control the name field then