# How to enable a submit button when having a default input value in a textfield when using Formik and Yup for form validation with MUI?

Tags: reactjs, forms, material-ui, formik, yup

I'm using Formik, Yup and MUI for form validation. And I would like to know how to manage Formik properties in order to enable a form button when I have a default value in a textfield component.

The idea is to have a default value for the TextfieldWrapper component, for which I receive the value as children and assign it to the `value` property of the component as long as it has a children as input, otherwise I show the empty field to fill.

The problem I have is that when I finish filling out the form when there is a default value in the textfield, the submit button is not enabled.

I noticed that Formik's `isValid` property is kept false which is why the button is not enabled. On the other hand, the error Yup returns when I query the `errors.batchNo` property is that the batchNo field is required. So it seems that the default value in the textfield is not being recognized as a valid value.

I have customized the TextField component of MUI as follow:

```
import React from 'react';
import { TextField } from '@mui/material';
import { useField } from 'formik';

const TextfieldWrapper = ({ name, ...otherProps }) => {
  const [field, meta] = useField(name);
  const configTextfield = {
    ...field,
    ...disabled,
    ...otherProps,
    fullWidth: true,
    variant: 'outlined',
  };

  if (meta && meta.touched && meta.error) {
    configTextfield.error = true;
    configTextfield.helperText = meta.error;
  }
  return <TextField {...configTextfield} />;
};
```

This is the snippet code for the form:

```
const valSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  batchNo: Yup.string()
    .required('Required'),
  item: Yup.string().required('Required'),
  price: Yup.string().required('Required'),
});

const ItemForm = ({ children }) => {
return (
    <Grid container>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Container maxWidth="md">
          <div>
            <Formik
              initialValues={initialValues}
              validationSchema={valSchema}
              onSubmit={(values) => {
                localHandleSubmit(values);
              }}
            >
              {({ dirty, isValid, errors }) => (
                <Form>
                  <Grid container spacing={2}>
                    {children ? (
                      <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <TextfieldWrapper name="batchNo" label="Batch No" value={children} />
                      </Grid>
                    ) : (
                      <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <TextfieldWrapper name="batchNo" label="Batch No" />
                      </Grid>
                    )}
                    <Grid item xs={6}>
                      <TextfieldWrapper name="item" label="Item" />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={6}>
                      <TextfieldWrapper name="price" label="Price" />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={6}>
                      <Typography>{dirty ? 'true' : 'false'}</Typography>
                      <Typography>{isValid ? 'true' : 'false'}</Typography>
                      <Typography>{errors.batchNo}</Typography>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                      <Button
                        fullWidth
                        variant="contained"
                        disabled={!isValid || !dirty}
                        type="submit"
                      >
                        {' '}
                        ADD
                      </Button>
                    </Grid>
                  </Grid>
                </Form>
              )}
            </Formik>
          </div>
        </Container>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};
```

I wonder how I can get the `isValid` property to be set to true so the submit button can be enable when I have a default input value for a textfield.

Comment: If you use formik, use formik. If you use controlled component, use controlled components. Don't mix the two and expect them to magically somehow understand eachother...

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what value `children` has, but I assume it's not a react component. Which is what you typically use the `children` props for making your code even more confusing for an outside reader.

Comment: `useField` returns `helpers` which contains `setValue` which you can call in a `useEffect` when `value` changes. But if you want the prop to be named value, don't pass it on to the `TextField` since that will mess it up.

Comment: @super, thanks for the recomendation. I'm new at this and used a youtube video to introduce me in the topic. On the other hand, `children` has a string value not a react component. So, I think the proper question would be how I can pass a string as a default value to a `Textfield` in order to work fine with formik.

Comment: Option 1. Make sure to set `initialValues` before the form is loaded. Option 2. Use setField to update formiks value once after mount. Option 3. Use setField every time `value` changes to update also when the prop changes.

Comment: As a 4th option you can pass `enableReinitialize` to formik, then updating `initialValues` will update the form even after mount.

Comment: @super, I have tried this: `{props.batchValue ? ( <TextfieldWrapper name="batchNo"  label="Batch No"  value={props.batchValue} onChange={(e) =>  handleChange(e); setFieldValue('batchNo', props.batchValue); }} />  ) : (<TextfieldWrapper name="batchNo" label="Batch. No" /> )}` But it is not working thus it still keeps button disabled, the idea is that this form is used in another component in which a prop is passed from an API.

Comment: @super, I have also enabled `enableReinitialize` to formik.

Comment: So I gave you 4 ways of doing what you want, and you try something different and then tell me that's also not working...? Why not try any of the options I provided you instead? I'm on my phone so can't write you an example.

Comment: @super, I though you meant to `setFieldValue` from formik when mentioned third option. I've tried 4th option too, but it is not working. Yeah, it would be great if you could give some example.

Comment: If onChange always sets the field value to props.batchNo then... How do you imagine that would work? I said you could change it every time the prop change. From a useEffect.

Comment: @super, ok thanks. what I didn't know was how to access the formik context to use setFieldValue in useEffect, this helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60358836/how-to-formik-setfieldvalue-in-useeffect-hook!

Comment: As my previous comment said, you can also get it from helpers returned by useField that you are already using in TextFieldWrapper.